# How to compute the marginal CDF of a joint density?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

I am trying to compute the cumulative distribution function of a random  variable $u$ that has the following density:

$$f(u) = \int_{1}^\infty \frac{e^{-4uv}}{v^5}dv$$

for $u \gt  0$.

#### What I've tried

I've tried computing this integral, giving a function $f(u)$, and then calculating $\int_{-\infty}^x f(u) du$, obtaining the CDF of the density. But I always get some weird results from this integral. I know that there must be a better way to solve this using the fact that this is a joint density, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone please give me any hint or advice?

Comment: What are your "weird results" ?  I think your joint density is missing a multiplicative factor of 20 so that it integrates to 1.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19 gives you a good set of tools to evaluate this.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Not sure who you're asking but it would appear to be $\frac{20 \exp (-4 u v)}{v^5}$ (once the correct multiplier is applied) and if $u$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Note that $u$ must not be negative, for then the integral no longer exist. Moreover, you can simply excahnge the order of integrations, which leads to a different power in the denominator of the integrand. The resulting integral can be looked up on the page to which @whuber linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, consider the distribution whose density is

$$f_p(u, \theta) = \theta C_p\int_1^\infty v^{-p} e^{-\theta u v}\,\mathrm{d}v = \theta C_pE_p(\theta u)$$

for $u \gt 0$ and parameters $p\gt 0,$ $\theta \gt 0.$  $E_p$ is the [Exponential Integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19) function and $C_p$ is a normalizing constant (which we will find at the end).  Notice, for future reference, that

$$E_{p+1}(0) = \int_1^\infty v^{-(p+1)}\,\mathrm{d}v = \frac{1}{p}.$$

Moreover, since for any $z\gt 0$

$$
0\le E_p(z) = \int_1^\infty v^{-p} e^{-zv}\,\mathrm{d}v\le  \int_1^\infty e^{-zv}\,\mathrm{d}v = \frac{1}{z},$$

it follows from the Squeeze Theorem (for limits) that

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} E_p(z) = 0.$$

The distribution function (cdf) is, by definition,

$$F_p(u,\theta) = \int_0^u f_p(z)\,\mathrm{d}z =  C_p \int_0^u  E_p(\theta z)\,\theta\mathrm{d}z =  C_p \int_0^{\theta u}  E_p(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.$$

The integrand defining $E_p$ is smooth and decreasing so quickly at its upper limit that we may interchange the operations of differentiating and integrating, showing

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}E_{p+1}(z) &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\int_1^\infty v^{-(p+1)} e^{-zv}\,\mathrm{d}v\\&=\int_1^\infty  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}v^{-(p+1)} e^{-zv}\,\mathrm{d}v\\&=-\int_1^\infty v^{-p} e^{-zv}\,\mathrm{d}v\\&=-E_p(z).
\end{aligned}$$

It is immediate (by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) that

$$F_p(u,\theta) = C_p \left[E_{p+1}(0) - E_{p+1}(\theta u)\right] = C_p \left[\frac{1}{p} - E_{p+1}(\theta u)\right].$$

Finally, since $\lim_{u\to\infty}F_p(u,\theta)=1$ (by the Law of Total Probability), we find

$$1 = \lim_{u\to\infty}C_p \left[\frac{1}{p} - E_{p+1}(\theta u)\right] = \frac{C_p}{p},$$

showing $C_p = p$ and giving

> $$F_p(u,\theta) = 1 - pE_{p+1}(\theta u).$$

Set $p=5$ and $\theta=4$ for the answer to the question.  Here are graphs of the density and its cdf:

[image: Figure]

These were drawn in gray using the analytical solution.  As a check, over them are plotted, in red, the values obtained from numerically computing the single integral for $f$ and the double integral for $F.$  The `R` code that generated these graphs follows.

```R
#
# Solution.
#
library(expint)
f <- function(u, p, theta) theta * p * expint_En(theta * u, p)
F <- function(u, p, theta) 1 - p * expint_En(theta * u, p+1)
#
# Brute force verification using numerical integration.
#
f. <- Vectorize(function(u, p, theta, ...) {
  theta * p * integrate(function(v) exp(-theta * u * v) / v^p, 1, Inf, ...)$value
}, "u")
F. <- Vectorize(function(u, p, theta, ...) {
  integrate(function(z) f.(z, p, theta), 0, u, ...)$value
}, "u")
#
# Example.
#
p <- 5
theta <- 4
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
curve(f(x, p, theta), 0, 1.5, n=501, lwd=2, col=gray(0.25),
      xlab="u", ylab="Density", 
      main=bquote(f[.(p)](u, .(theta))))
curve(f.(x, p, theta), add = TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2, lty=2)

curve(F(x, p, theta), 0, 1.5, n=501, lwd=2, col=gray(0.25),
      yaxp=c(0,1,1),
      xlab="u", ylab="Probability", 
      main=bquote(F[.(p)](u, .(theta))))
curve(F.(x, p, theta), add = TRUE, col="Red", lwd=2, lty=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: many thanks, so great when your answer is accompanied with fully replicable r code! +1

Comment: @Max I just hope my redefinition of `F` doesn't cause any problems ;-).

Answer (score 4):

***Warning:***  this answer/approach lacks mathematical rigor and relies on *Mathematica* to do the heavy lifting.

From looking at what is given for the marginal density for $U$

$$f(u)=\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-4 u v}}{v^5} dv$$

one can surmise that the joint pdf for $U$ and $V$ is proportional to $\frac{e^{-4 u v}}{v^5}$.  I say "proportional" because the integral over the values of $U$ and $V$ integrates to 1/20 and not to 1.  Therefore a multiplier of 20 is needed.

```
Integrate[Exp[-4 u v]/v^5, {v, 1, \[Infinity]}, {u, 0, \[Infinity]}]
(* 1/20 *)
```

So the joint pdf is $\frac{20 e^{-4 u v}}{v^5}$.  Integrating over $v$ gets the pdf for $U$:

```
Integrate[20 Exp[-4 u v]/v^5, {v, 1, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> u > 0]
```

$$\frac{5}{3} \left(e^{-4 u} \left(3-4 u \left(8 u^2-2 u+1\right)\right)-128 u^4 \text{Ei}(-4 u)\right)$$

where $\text{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).  The cdf is then found with

```
Integrate[5/3 (E^(-4 u) (3 - 4 u (1 - 2 u + 8 u^2)) - 128 u^4 ExpIntegralEi[-4 u]), {u, 0, z}, 
  Assumptions -> z > 0] /. z -> u
```

$$\frac{1}{3} \left(-128 u^5 \text{Ei}(-4 u)+e^{-4 u} \left(u \left(3-4 u \left(8 u^2-2 u+1\right)\right)-3\right)+3\right)$$

Here are plots of the pdf and cdf:

[image: PDF of u]

[image: CDF of u]

**Update**

I followed @whuber 's suggestion below to treat the pdf symbolically using the general form in his answer to see if *Mathematica* would then produce a simpler form for the pdf and cdf.  And it did.

```
pdf = \[Theta] p Integrate[v^(-p) Exp[-\[Theta] u v], {v, 1, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> u > 0 && \[Theta] > 0 && p > 0] // FunctionExpand
```

$$\theta  p (\theta  u)^{p-1} \Gamma (1-p,u \theta )$$

```
cdf = Simplify[Integrate[pdf, {u, 0, w}, 
 Assumptions -> \[Theta] > 0 && p > 0 && w > 0] /. w -> u // FunctionExpand, 
 Assumptions -> u > 0 && \[Theta] > 0 && p > 0]
```

$$(\theta  u)^p \Gamma (1-p,u \theta )-e^{\theta  (-u)}+1$$

where $\Gamma (1-p,u \theta )$ is the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: These formulas are correct and agree with my solution.  They arise because it appears *Mathematica* doesn't know how to simplify the general Exponential Integral function.  Perhaps applying `FullSimplify` would help clean up the formula.

Comment: @whuber.  Thanks.  I did try `FullSimplify` (with `Assumptions -> u>0`) and `FunctionExpand` and got no simplification.

Comment: Did you try this using the constants $5$ and $4$ as stated in the question or by treating them as symbolic variables?  In the latter case, if *Mathematica* can evaluate the integral it almost certainly will give it in a simpler form (perhaps as a confluent hypergeometric function, incomplete Gamma function, or Exponential Integral).  (I no longer have access to *Mathematica* or I would try this myself...)

Comment: @whuber I have not tried that but I will shortly.  In the meantime there is the "free" version of *Mathematica* called "Wolfram Engine for Developers".  Essentially it is "free" and "legal" as long as you don't make money using it.  (Of course, the license is more specific than that but I think it's essentially a similar license as "SAS on demand for academics".)

Comment: Thank you for that tip! `FullSimplify` isn't actually needed.  `wolframscript -code "Assuming[u > 0, Integrate[Exp[-4 u x]/x^p, {x,1,Infinity}]]"` returns `ExpIntegralE[p, 4*u]`, as one would hope.  Following that up with an evaluation of `"Integrate[ExpIntegralE[5, 4*u], {u, 0, y}]"` gives `(1 - 5*ExpIntegralE[6, 4*y])/20`.

Comment: @whuber.  I suppose you already know about this link (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198839/how-to-add-a-front-end-to-the-free-wolfram-engine/199127#199127) which apparently does a reasonable job of emulating a *Mathematica* front end.  (I have my own personal copy of *Mathematica* so I haven't tried it yet.)

Comment: Nice!  I had planned to search that site for something like this solution.  I now have a Jupyter front end running on Win 11.  I am glad not to have to do these integrals with pencil and paper anymore :-).